# How To Create Photo Based Table View Cell With Custom Text Placement?

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview

I like how the Trulia Mobile iPhone app search result has the photo span the entire table view cell and puts the text details in the lower left corner. How does one code that? Is there a tutorial that covers such an approach?

The closest solution I see is the book "iOS 7 By Tutorials", Chapter 8, section "Blur effects”.

[image: Trulia Mobile app search results]

Comment: I don't know of a specific tutorial, but you can use a custom table view cell as your prototype cell. Add some labels and outlets to put the text where you want and set the background of the cell to be an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so hard!

1. Make a prototype UITableView
2. Make a custom UITableViewCell class
3. link class to your storyboard
4. Put your labels and stuff in your UITableViewCell prototype
5. Link your outlets etc to your code (UITableViewCell Class)
6. Setup your UITableView rowForIndexPath by doing: `CustomClass *cell
   = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`

Try finding a tutorials how to setup an custom prototype cell

EDIT:
[Here is a link](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/)